# Hybrid Automated & Manual rest API documentation using Enunciate

Tags: web-services, rest, enunciate

Does Enunciate support the following hybrid modes:

1. It processes the available classes to generate the documentation.
2. Read manual documentation from some JSON/XML/TEXT file to add to the generated documentation in (1)

If Enunciate does not support this, are there other tools out which can address our need.